# How to show complete right triangle? right edge cut off

Tags: html, css

I'm currently struggling with an aesthetic problem. My triangle button is being cut off at the right corner and it's not a sight, it's basically a right-sided trapezium.

What i did was make an input field, and aligned a triangle submit button at the end of the input field.

[image: output]

What's the cause of this?

```css
.submit_btn {
  display: block;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #bc2ac1;
  background-color: transparent;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submit_btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="form_name" action="">
    <label class="name" for="name">What's your name?</label>
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input class="name_field" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default padding on your `input` element was interfering with the cool CSS border trick. Add:

```
padding: 0;
```

I changed the element to a `<button>` and removed all the code not directly related to styling the purple triangle. I also reformatted the triangle border trick code to make it a little clearer. This is all for demo purposes. Just adding the padding line to your code will fix it.

```css
.submit_btn {
  /* this fixes the tip of the triangle */
  padding: 0; 

  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 17.3px solid #bc2ac1;
  border-right: none;

  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form class="form_name" action="">
    <label class="name" for="name">What's your name?</label>
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input class="name_field" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        <button class="submit_btn" type="submit" value=""></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not horizontally center !!

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` to the main container to move your triangle to right and for moving your triangle to in input field, I used `translateY` property.

```css
.input_wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.submit_btn {
  display: block;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 17.3px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #bc2ac1;
  background-color: transparent;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateX(-25px);
}

.submit_btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="form_name" action="">
    <label class="name" for="name">What's your name?</label>
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input class="name_field" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```